# Clicking on hamburger icon sometimes does not open navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

when click on hamburger icon sometimes not open navigation drawer but sometime work perfectlySometime issue with click on hamburger icon.Help me solve out this issue.My code is here :-

activity_main.xml :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Kotlin File :-

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navFormula -> {

        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your nav is correctly instantiated as fallow

```
...
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
toggle.syncState()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create your own toolbar on your xml, 
on your activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_margin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/toolTitle" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then, on your activity, on create, put :

```
    //set the custom toolbar as the action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    //set the NavigationItemListener
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        item.isChecked = true

        //close drawer when an item is clicked
        drawer.closeDrawers()
        when (item.itemId) {

        }
        false
    }

    //open drawer when the hamburger icon is clicked
    menuIcon.setOnClickListener {
        drawer.openDrawer(nav_view, true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following settings, it would always open Navigation Drawer after clicked Hamburger icon:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {    
    ...
    // Add Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.tb_settings))
    getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    ...
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    // Open Navigation Bar
    drawer_layout.openDrawer(nav_view, true)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put this in main Activity for the hamburger icon to function as intended.

```
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```